# Tag synonyms (optimize -> optimization)

Tags: discussion

I can't propose tag synonyms so I'm just posting here. I think we should make [optimize](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimize) a synonym of [optimization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization). Also, the only existing synonym for it, [effeciency](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effeciency), is misspelled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went ahead and did it. Thanks!