# Create Tag Clean Code

Tags: discussion, tags

My reputation is too low to create the tag `clean-code`. I really miss this tag since  [clean code](https://clean-code-developer.com/) is a major aspect of code reviews (just nowadays more than in the past)!

ok let's have a closer look at clean code:

### red belt:

- Don´t Repeat Yourself (DRY)
- Keep it simple, stupid (KISS)
- Beware of Optimizations!
- Favour Composition over Inheritance (FCoI)
- Integration Operation Segregation Principle (IOSP)

### orange belt:

- Single Level of Abstraction (SLA)
- **Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)**
- Separation of Concerns (SoC)
- [...]

### yellow belt:

- Interface Segregation Principle (ISP)
- Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP)
- Liskov Substitution Principle
- Principle of Least Astonishment
- Information Hiding Principle
- [...]

### green belt:

- Open Closed Principle
- **Tell, don´t ask**
- Law of Demeter
- [...]
- Inversion of Control Container

### blue belt:

- [...]
- You Ain´t Gonna Need It (YAGNI)

if you use the [search and look for "clean code"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=clean%20code) you find many related and high voted items...

Comment: [Related meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9082), which asked if it should be added, but was ignored.

Comment: @Peilonrayz - where does that meta question you reference ask for clean-code to be added? Additionally, just because there's no answers, does not mean that it has been ignored completely. Have you considered that the meta-question you referenced simply has too many questions/concerns in it and it is impossible to formulate a single answer to it?

Comment: @rolfl Yeah, there was a lot of questions and that one was 'ignored'. What word would you prefer me to use?

Comment: Can you find a question that could *not* be tagged with "clean-code"? It's my impression that every single question on the site is looking for clean(-er) code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[clean-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-code) would be a meta-tag - a tag that describes what you want the code to look like, not what the code is, or does. Additionally, all questions should be asking to review for clean code, for readability, and for a number of other things that are common to good, production code.

So, [clean-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-code) would be a bad tag for Code Review, and we are actively trying to reduce the use of meta-tags.

Note, in 2014 we actively removed that tag: [Should we do something about our meta tags?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/should-we-do-something-about-our-meta-tags).

Comment: Clean code conflicts with performance and memory optimization. We have tags for the latter two, and people come here for them. So no not all Code Reviews ask for 'clean code'.

Comment: maybe in 2014 there was no need for that - but things changed ever since then.

Comment: @Peilonrayz WHAT? "Clean code conflicts with performance and memory optimization" No... no it doesn't. Clean Code is a nonfunctional requirement and optimizations usually are functional requirements. That's a difference in kind. While some optimizations make code harder to read or maintain, they are not conflicting goals. For the vast majority of use cases, cleaner code is also more performant code.

Comment: @MartinFrank the considerations that went into burninating the tag back then are not really dependent on the time or state of the industry...

Comment: i'm honest to you guys - most of our company reviews turn around clean code and most of my question on codereview here do the same... and i am activly lookging for question concerning clean code - since i know it and can help with this topic. this tag would greatly improve my posts and help me to find answers... i can understand that you vote against this tag...

Comment: @Vogel612 We are in agreement in the first half of your second to last sentence. I disagree with your last as better performance, speed or memory, normally incurs a cost to clean code. Whilst sometimes it's small and negligible, it's still a trade-off.

Comment: note: did you ever do a search concerning `Separation of Concerns` there are very much high ranked question on this topic and some of them have the misleading `design-pattern` tag on it. that was the very reason to instantiate this question....or look at `KISS` - tons of entries they all belong to one aspect of code reviews: clean code

Comment: @martinfrank dysfunctional tags is one thing, adding more dysfunctional tags doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: OK, I'm glad I lead this discussion :-) thanks you all for your input and clearing out the intention of the usage of tags here...